# output results of mysql query that is dependant on selected rows from MySQL array

Tags: php, mysql, session, checkbox

I have a PHP page that outputs the results of a MySQL query. each outputted row has a checkbox. The user will check the desired rows and click a viewdetails button. I want to then display the results of the MySQL query that is dependant on the users selections.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 'selected Checkbox's'
```

My PHP page is as follows:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "hulamin_hulamin", "Hulamin2011")or die("cannot connect");    
    mysql_select_db("hulamin_loc")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql="select loadid as `Order Number`, LOCStatus as `Load Status`,count(loadid) as `Number of Cases`,sum(`Gross Mass`) as `Total Weight`, customer as Customer, transporttypename as `Transport Type` from despgoods_alldetails where loadid > 0 group by loadid";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);       ?> <table border=0>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form name="form1" method="post">
                <table border=1
                    <tr>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        <th width=150>Order number</th>                     
                        <th width=150>Status</th>  
                        <th width=150>Number of Cases</th>
                        <th width=130>Total Weight</th>
                        <th width=300>Customer</th> 
                        <th width=150>Transport Type</th> 
                                            </tr> <?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name=check[]  value="<?php echo $rows['Order Number']; ?>"></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['Order Number']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['Load Status']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['Number of Cases']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['Total Weight']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['Customer']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $rows['Transport Type']; ?></td>

                    </tr>                                   

<?php
    } ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=7><input name="ViewDetails" type="submit" id="ViewDetails" value="ViewDetails"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php



                            $check=$_POST['check'];

                        if($_REQUEST['ViewDetails']=='ViewDetails'){

                        }
                   mysql_close(); ?> </table> </form> </td> </tr> </table>
```

After clicking the submit button I want the query to run and output results

```
select * from desp_goods where loadid=$checkboxes
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html for checkbox is

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" />
```

and your post $_POST array is something like this

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4);
```

and

MySQL query then should be:

```
select * from desp_goods where loadid IN (implode(',', $ids))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I am comfortable with the MySQL sytax. I am unsure how to carry the variable $check (as in above code) into the next page so query will be [ select * from desp_goods where load in ($check) ]

Comment: Thanks, I will try this? What does the 1,2,3,4 represent?

Comment: values of checkboxes. `<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="1" />` and so on.. replace 1,2,3...  with your values

Comment: Thanks @Janis, If I am retreiving from the array, and dont know how many checkboxes will be returned, how can I number each one. I need a dynamic way to do this. Thanks, Ryan

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4063/discussion-between-ryan-smith-and-janis-lankovskis)